Help with drywall dust, efflorescence or something else?
This stuff appears all over the bathroom floor of our home. We are sweeping it up weekly. Can anybody identify what it could possibly be? I do not know where its coming from. I basically can sweep up a smile pile of this weekly.


We need pictures of where it is coming from.

Bird nest in the vent hose?

I dont know where its coming from. It just shows up on my bathroom floor. There is one vent in the bathroom which I have covered with a screen to catch anything that may fly out and its clean. So I dont think its coming from the vent.

Is the bath floor tile?  This could be a sign that there is water under the tile if it appears in the grout lines.

Does it dissolve quickly in water? If so, it's efflorescence; if not, it's likely organic.
